# Testing a remote service that uses Messenger

Tags: android, testing, service, junit

I'm developing an Android remote service that [uses Messenger to pass messages from/to different applications](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample).

I'm having trouble setting up the JUnit test class, since the `bindService()` for the `ServiceTestCase<T>` class has no `bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)` method, but only a `bindService(Intent)`. This is no use since I need to specify a `ServiceConnection` to be able to listen to incoming messages from the service.

How can I solve this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @androiddeveloper This questions already has an accepted answer. Also that answer was posted 2 years after my question and it doesn't even answer my question (which is about JUnit testing with Messenger).

Comment: @androiddeveloper No worries :) When you read this we can delete these comments as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using

```
getContext().bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)
```

instead of

```
bindService(Intent)
```

**EDIT**: I was focusing this the wrong way. Please read [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361285/android-service-not-launched-by-junit-test) to do it the right way.