# Android: How to wait for a callback to occur

Tags: android, service, junit, wait

Goal: A method that start a service, wait for the connection be ready and then return.

This constructor start a (GPS) service. I need to be sure that the *onServiceConnected* was called before returning from the *constructor*:

```
public GPS(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GpsService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
    context.bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);        

    // Want to wait here for the callback to onServiceConnected before returning.
    ...
    }

public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
   ...
}
```

Why? I am writing *Android Junit Tests*, and the *testSomething*() methods fails because they run before the service get connected. And because the callback is made for Android, not for me, I can't apply (I believe) a traditional Thread/wait/notify solution.

I wrote a tracking app that works fine because code always check and does nothing if connection is not yet ready, but Junit tests are another story.

Comment: This question and answer describes how to set up a `ServiceTestCase` for testing bound services: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361285/android-service-not-launched-by-junit-test

Comment: My utility class GPS is not a service; it just uses one.

Comment: So? Your problem, based on your question, is in how you are testing the service. Hence, you might consider reading a StackOverflow question and answer about how to test a service.